# Can't determine the cause of errors in this Javascript "for - of" loop

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

[image]

This is a screenshot of Edge's debugger window.  The code isn't running, but as you can see, there are little red squigglies in the debugger window; the interpreter/compiler/whatsit isn't happy, but there is no indication of what it doesn't like specifically.  The output window is clear, there is no "hover tip", nor any other explanation I can find.

This is practically a direct copy of the example [from the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onBeforeSendHeaders).

Any guidance is immensely appreciated.

Comment: Edge 12? Because that is the lowest Edge support for of

Comment: Not sure if I'm looking at the right version, but I'm using "`Microsoft Edge 38.14393.1066.0`" and "`Microsoft EdgeHTML 14.14393`" according to the Settings dialog

Comment: I put the function in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kju1y4oe/) and it runs smooth at least in Edge 15 :o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it appears to be the support isn't there from the browser you are using. So I would suggest changing the iteration from a `for..of` to a `for..in`. Something along the lines of (edited from @agrm's fiddle):

```js
function rewriteUserAgentHeader(e) {
  for (var index in e.requestHeaders) {
    if (e.requestHeaders[index].name.toLowerCase() === "user-agent")
    { e.requestHeaders[index].value = "it worked!"; }
  }
  return {requestHeaders: e.requestHeaders};
}

var headers = {
  requestHeaders: [
    {name: "user-agent", value: "to be modified"},
    {name: "something-else", value: "to be left alone"}
  ]
};

console.log( rewriteUserAgentHeader(headers) )
```